# How to import 3D models in Zappar WebAR Project based from user select?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parceljs, web-ar

I want to import different 3D models in my webAR Zappar project based from user chose; When user select a character name, **modelPath Variable** must be change to selected model file path. my question is how i can use a string for changing the path and model file?

I tried through the following method.

```
let modelPath  ='../assets/model.glb';
let model = new URL(modelPath , import.meta.url).href;
```

Result of above codes is  : file:///assets/model.glb

But when i change codes to

```
let model = new URL('../assets/model.glb', import.meta.url).href;
```

result is (*I need this result*) : https://IPADDRESS:PORT/model.01234567.glb?12345678901234

for more information you can see https://github.com/zappar-xr/threejs-example-instant-tracking-gltf-loader/tree/master